# Convert managed List<string> to unmanaged char**

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, marshalling

I have to send List of string from c# code to c++ unmanaged dll. for this I have created wrapper of vc++.
So now send List from c# and convert it into char **.

From C#:

```
void SendIPList(List<String> ipList);
```

VC++ wrapper:

```
void SendIPList(List<String*>* ipList);
```

In C++ Dll:

```
void ipList(char **iplist);
```

So there is a need to change something in vc++ wrapper?

Comment: In the wrapper it should probably be `List<String>* ipList` or `List<char*>* ipList`

Comment: After changing I am getting error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'char *', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

Comment: Maybe you can try `Marshal`?